# iOS SwiftUI - ForEach multidimensional 2D Array

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to ForEach a 2D array based on this answer here:

[SwiftUI ForEach get element AND index in 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59734553/swiftui-foreach-get-element-and-index-in-2d-array)

```
ForEach(0..<memesSplit.endIndex) { index in
    
    ForEach(memesSplit[index], id: \.memeid){_ in
        
    }
    
}
```

and get this warning:

> Non-constant range: argument must be an integer literal

I looked it up and it means the app will crash because of "out of index" in case an item will be removed.

So how to do this correctly?

When I do what I've tried first:

```
ForEach(memesSplit) { arr in
    
    ForEach(arr, id: \.memeid){ meme in
        
    }
    
}
```

then I get this error:

> Referencing initializer 'init(_:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that
> '[MemeModel]' conform to 'Identifiable'

Based on the mentioned question I tried:

```
ForEach(self.memeModel.memesSplit) { arr in

    ForEach(arr, id: \.memeid){ meme in

    }

}
```

And couple other syntaxes but get all kind of other errors where I don't know what they mean

This is the model of the inner array:

```
struct MemeModel: Codable {
    var memeid: Int
    var title: String
    var pic: String
    var size: String
    var userid: Int
    var nickname: String
    var commentcount: Int
    var time: Int
    var secondsago: Int
    var checked: Int
    var liked: Int
    var disliked: Int
    var saved: Int
    var voteup: Int
    var votedown: Int
}
```

and this is how I declare the 2D array:

```
@State private var memesSplit = [[MemeModel]]()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Referencing initializer 'init(\_:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that 'Planet' conform to 'Identifiable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69393430/referencing-initializer-init-content-on-foreach-requires-that-planet-c)

Comment: I've seen this, no it does not

Comment: Please check out what I just added to the question at the end, do you an that? It looks like the question you all are keep referring to is a normal custom array, not multidimensional/2D @jnpdx

Comment: You could create a new wrapper type (MemeSection?) that stores an array of MemeModels and have it conform to Identifiable.

Comment: This is the normal way and I'm aware of it but I need what I'm asking and it's too much and actually unnecessary to explain why I need it that way

Comment: Basically it's because LazyVGrid is underdeveloped very basic crap compared to what Android has to offer and I need to do workarounds